# AddFirst method doesn't work

Tags: c#, arrays

**Situation:**

Hey there, I've made a program that can perform multiple functions with linear arrays, I didn't want to use the premade array class, so I have a few methods like addFirst, addLast, removeFirst, removeLast etc.

My program (Not part of the class) generates a random number for the addFirst method to add to the "first" position of the array

*whereas*

My program (Not part of the class) generates a random number for the addFirst method to add to the "Last" position of the array

**Problem:**

My problem is, my addFirst doesn't seem to work correctly, I know this because when I run my displayUI method the values that should be in the first position of the array values are instead at the last position of the array.

*What happens after a console.writeline():*

```
Values currently in array: 11, 21, 80, 25
```

*Whereas, what should happen:*

`Values currently in array: 25, 80, 21, 11`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, here is my code for addFirst:

```
public void addFirst(int value) //Adds an item to the first position in the array.
{
    if (isFull())
    {
        throw new Exception("List Full");
    }
    else
    {

        for (int i = count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            values[i] = values[i--];
        }
        values[count] = value;
        count++;

    }
}
```

Comment: List<int> or debug maybe?

Comment: If this isn't a homework assignment, you should just be using the `List<int>` class and use the `InsertAt()` method. If it is a homework assignment, you should bring a question like this up with your teacher, so that they can better-facilitate the understanding of the problem that _they_ want you to have.

Comment: May I ask you a question: is it a learning task or you just like reinventing the wheel?

Comment: A piece of advice: 1) draw array states before and after the operation; 2) use simple constructions; 3) trace your code line by line in debugger.

Comment: If I'm honest, yes this is a homework assignment to contruct an array class without relying on the built-in array functionality.

I got given it on friday night, I'm not in college again until wednesday and I'm spending my weekend doing this.

I constructed this from a class diagram today, my only issue is, my addLast method is working as I expect it too, but my addFirst's output isn't what I expect it to be. This assignment isn't due anytime soon, I just want it out of the way.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            for (int i = count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                values[i] = values[i-1];
            }

            values[0] = value;
```

At the end you should have `values[0]` not `values[count]`. You want to add on first position which is 0.

**EDIT** After your comment. I don't know how you are taking count and the array because of that I put it as parameters in my case !

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] test = new int[5];
        test[0] = 10;
        test[1] = 20;
        test[2] = 40;
        test[3] = 80;

        addFirst(123, test.Length, test);

        foreach(int i in test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

    }

    public static void addFirst(int value, int count, int[] test) 
    {
        //Check for full list done by you already

        for (int i = count-1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            test[i] = test[i-1];
        }

        test[0] = value;
    }
```

Here is code which is working. You can check your logic for other problems.

Comment: When I do this my displayUI method returns only the last entered value, if I entered '50' to the array last, then it would output 50,0,0,0

I don't get this same issue with addLast, that works as expected.

Comment: It kinda works, if I added 9, 21, 10, and 88 it would only show 9,21, 10, 0...88 wouldn't show up.

Comment: @Method it will show 0, because when you write int[] p = new int[5]. You are creating array with 5 zero elements !

Comment: If my addFirst keeps adding the next number to the first position of the array, if I entered. 16,26,36,46 in that order, then 46 would be the first position in the array, that shows up fine, as do the second and third, but 16 (The last position) instead appears as 0 in the array, when it should be 16. Any idea what could be causing my issue?

Comment: This affects everything else, as it doesn't store 16 at all, and instead stores 0 in the fourth position.

Comment: FIXED IT, had to move the count++; to the start, thanks for your help!

Btw, if you're still here, how could I clear the array of all values at once, if you don't mind helping out.

Answer (score 2):

one obvious thing you need to fix:

```
           values[i] = values[i-1];
```

also probably want to move `count++` before the for loop

and since you want to add first (and not last)

```
values[0] = value;
```

Comment: What, this does the exact same thing as my code that's already there right? '--' =/= '-1'?

Comment: no, it is not the same thing. one changes the value of `i` which you should not do in a loop

Comment: @Method - `values[i] = values[i--];` is equivalent of `values[i] = values[i]; i = i-1;`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how your array grows. I think that you took a very large array and are just adding to it? For example an array of 100 elements.

The one thing that you should notice is the difference between `i--` and `i-1`. `i--` first puts the `i` as the index of Values and then decrements `i` value and puts it in `i`. In other words `i--` means `i=i-1;`. So your for loop does the shift upside down. Consider `count = 5`: at fist execution of for loop `i` would be 5. First the right side of the assignment executes so the value in the right side would have the index of 5 AND THEN the `i` would decrement so `i` would be 4 so the assignment would be values[4], values[5] and so on. So you are shifting left instead of right.

Your second mistake is that you must say `Values[0]=value;` instead of `values[count]=value;`