# Removing the first/last value in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

**Problem:**

I'm trying to remove the first value in an array using these methods I've written:

**removeFirst()**

```
 public int removeFirst() //removes the first item from the array
        {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new Exception("List is Empty");


            count--;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                values[i] = values[i + 1];



            }

            int value = values[0];

            return value;
        }
```

**Removelast()**

```
public int removeLast() //todo //removes the last item from the array
        {
            if (isEmpty())
        throw new Exception("List is Empty");

    count--;
    return values[count];

        }
```

**displayUI()**

```
public void displayUI()//displays contents of list
        {
            Console.Write("Values currently in array: ");
            foreach (var item in values)
                Console.Write( item.ToString() + ", ");


        }
```

The problem is, when I use my DisplayUI() method that shows me the values that are currently in my values[] array, the value isn't removed, it's set to values[0], and right now I don't know a way around this.

Say if I entered the following numbers into my array using my addFirst() method: `6, 76, 65, 13.`

Then, when I run my removeFirst() method a few times (Which removes the arrays first value) I get this:

```
'6, 76, 13, 13'
'6, 13, 13, 13'
'13, 13, 13, 13'
```

I'd like it to remove "6" instead of exchange 65 for 13 (The last array value), and I have no idea why It does that.

I'd like the output to be:

```
'76, 65, 13, 0'
```

for this example. (Since the first position is empty, and all other positions can move up by 1)

How would I do this?

**Problem 2:**

Also attempting to do the inverse for removeLast()

The issue with my removeLast() method is that when I run my displayUI method, nothing changes, it still thinks that all of the items are in the array, which they must be if it's returning them.

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703096/addfirst-method-doesnt-work and the other array-list implementation question you asked? If this is homework, you should consult with your teacher to ensure you are actually learning what they want you to learn. Otherwise, just use `List<T>`.

Comment: I can't use list. I would if I could. It sounds so much simpler than this.

Comment: Then this is homework.

Comment: It is, but I'm doing this early before it's due, been trying to understand this stuff all day, this is setup for a project that's due in late December, like I've said in previous posts, I don't get to talk to my teacher again until Wednesday, so I'm trying to get help wherever I can.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your remove code, except maybe the return value. Maybe you want to return the value that was removed? If that's the case `int value = values[0]` should be before the for loop. Otherwise look elsewhere for the bug.

Comment: @rpattiso tried that, and yeah it's trying to return the value that was removed. Same logic error though.

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of DisplayUI, addFirst and removeLast.

Comment: I'm running your `removeFirst` code and it functions correctly and NOT as you describe in your question.

Comment: Then I don't get where I've went wrong.

Comment: It's really hard to tell from the code you've posted. RemoveLast is different than removeFirst  (it just decrements a counter and returns an item from the array). What is `count` actually used for?

Comment: @ Rufus L The count variable records how many values are currently in the array, for instance, if four values are in the array, count = 4; When I run removeLast() the counter decrements by '1' and when I run addFirst() the counter increments by '1' if the counter goes above 4 then it throws an exception. I have a localcounter in my program.cs that adds a second layer to make sure count > 4 doesn't happen. Still stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to get rid of the `count` variable, unless there's some other reason for keeping it. It's most likely causing hard-to-catch problems and I don't see where it adds value.

Since you have global access to your array (which is bad design, but fine for beginner level course), you can just use the .Length property (unless this is prohibited).

For example, you might try something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the contents of the array to the console
/// </summary>
private static void DisplayArray()
{
    ThrowIfArrayNullOrEmpty();

    Console.WriteLine("Values currently in array: {0}", string.Join(", ", values));
}

/// <summary>
/// Adds the integer to the start of the array and everything else to the next index
/// </summary>
/// <param name="firstValue">The integer to add</param>
private static void AddFirst(int firstValue)
{
    // First remove the last item (this will clear a space in the first position)
    RemoveLast();

    // Then update the first item
    values[0] = firstValue;
}

/// <summary>
/// Moves all items to the index before them, and initializes the last item to zero
/// </summary>
public static void RemoveFirst()
{
    ThrowIfArrayNullOrEmpty();

    // Move each item to the index before it
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        values[i] = values[i + 1];
    }

    // Set the last item to zero
    values[values.Length - 1] = 0;
}

/// <summary>
/// Moves all other to the next index and initializes the first item to zero
/// </summary>
public static void RemoveLast()
{
    ThrowIfArrayNullOrEmpty();

    // Move each item to the previous index. Note that we have to start with the last
    // item and work our way forward, or else we overwrite a value before we move it 
    for (int i = values.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        values[i] = values[i - 1];
    }

    // Set the first item to zero
    values[0] = 0;
}

/// <summary>
/// Throws an exception if the array is null or empty
/// </summary>
public static void ThrowIfArrayNullOrEmpty()
{
    if (values == null) throw new Exception("Array is Null");
    if (values.Length == 0) throw new Exception("Array is Empty");
}
```